# Vim script check running platform

Tags: vim, osx, macintosh

```
" Get running OS
let os = ""
if has("win32")
  let os="win"
else
  if has("unix")
    let s:uname = system("uname")
    if s:uname == "Darwin"
      let os="mac"
    else
      let os="unix"
    endif
  endif
endif

" Brackets expanding
let preBracket="`"
if os=="mac"
  let preBracket="$"
endif

exe 'vnoremap' . preBracket . '1 <esc>`>a)<esc>`<i(<esc>'
exe 'vnoremap' . preBracket . '2 <esc>`>a]<esc>`<i[<esc>'
exe 'vnoremap' . preBracket . '3 <esc>`>a}<esc>`<i{<esc>'
exe 'vnoremap' . preBracket . '$ <esc>`>a"<esc>`<i"<esc>'
exe 'vnoremap' . preBracket . 'q <esc>`>a''<esc>`<i''<esc>'
exe 'vnoremap' . preBracket . 'e <esc>`>a"<esc>`<i"<esc>'
" Map auto complete of (, ", ', [
exe 'inoremap ' . preBracket . '1 ()<esc>i'
exe 'inoremap ' . preBracket . '2 []<esc>i'
exe 'inoremap ' . preBracket . '3 {}<esc>i'
exe 'inoremap ' . preBracket . '4 {<esc>o}<esc>O'
exe 'inoremap ' . preBracket . 'q ''''<esc>i'
exe 'inoremap ' . preBracket . 'e ""<esc>i'
```

As vimscript above I want to map the shortcut to key expand bracket depend on vim's platform. Actually my macbook use different layout but I love the ease of using ``` character in keyboard so I map to $ which stays at the same place on mac pro keyboard (da layout).

But it seems that the script works fine on linux but doesn't work on mac. Did I miss something or I need to add something to make this script work on Mac OSX ?

Comment: Are you using the MacVim? If so, use `has(macunix)` or `has(mac)` -- see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10139972/vim-hasmacunix-or-hasmac-do-not-work).

Comment: I use vim in mac terminal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i manage to answer my own question, for comparing string in vimscript we should use `=~` instead of `==` . The reverse one is `!~`

So edit this line `if s:uname == "Darwin"` to `if s:uname =~ "Darwin"` to make this little script work.

I rewrite this as function:

```
function! GetRunningOS()
  if has("win32")
    return "win"
  endif
  if has("unix")
    if system('uname')=~'Darwin'
      return "mac"
    else
      return "linux"
    endif
  endif
endfunction
let os=GetRunningOS()
```

In case, someone interest in my `.vimrc`, check my [dotFiles](https://github.com/nXqd/dotFiles)

Comment: There is actually a `has('mac')` value. No need to use uname in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Linux, OS X, FreeBSD, UNIX and a distro-specific (Debian) detection.

```
" OS Platform Detection
let g:platform = 0
let g:distro = 0
" more distros to detect:
"https://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/feature/11251.htm://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/feature/11251.html 
let g:uname = substitute(system("uname"), '\n\+$', '', '')
if filereadable("/etc/debian_version")
    let g:platform="Linux"
    let g:distro="Debian"
elseif has('mac')
    let g:platform="Darwin"
    let g:distro="OS X"
elseif g:uname == "FreeBSD"
    let g:platform="FreeBSD"
elseif has('unix')
    let g:platform="UNIX"
elseif has('win32') || has('win64') "win32 also matches on win64 so redundant
    let g:platform="Windows"
elseif has('win32unix')
    let g:platform="Cygwin"
else
    let g:platform="Unknown"
endif
```